# canvas animation - frame by frame

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

It's not working:

```
var ctx=document.getElementById("mycanvas").getContext('2d');
var image = new Image();
var firtImg=1;
var lastImg=75;

window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback) 
{
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame || 
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) 
    {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
}
)();


function draw(){
    //loop here for loading system
    if(firstImg< lastImg){
        image.src = 'iglesiafls'+(firstImg++)+'.png';
        ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,550,800,0,0,550,800);
        requestAnimFrame(draw);
        render();
    }    
}
```

I'm trying to achieve a frame by frame animation of 75 images using the canvas.

Comment: Does your function *render* actually exist?

Answer (score 1):

It might be an issue with timing -- specifically, your images may not be loaded when you are trying to use them here:

```
if(firstImg< lastImg){
    image.src = 'iglesiafls'+(firstImg++)+'.png';
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,550,800,0,0,550,800);
    requestAnimFrame(draw);
    render();
}
```

And if they aren't loaded, the call to drawImage will fail.  Have you tried replacing the drawImage call with something like:

```
ctx.arc( 200, 400, firstImg*10, 0, Math.PI * 2, 0 );
```

to draw a circle (or whatever) and verify your animation call is working?  Or, if you have access to a javascript debugger, setting a breakpoint?

Here's a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eXWrn/4/) -- you had a typo that probably isn't helping:  firstImg vs firtImg.

Comment: Hi man, thanks, but I can't make this work, I've just used your code copied and pasted on the page and nothing happens.

Comment: Does the draw function get called at all?  Pop an alert("draw"); in there and see if it's a canvas drawing issue or one with the animation request.   Also, does the fiddle work in your browser?

Comment: fiddle worked in my browser but when I put the code into any page it doesn't work at all. I'm using dreamweaver and I'm simply doing a html 5 page...but nothing works.